# Smooth 12V pwm signal running at 4 KHz

Tags: pwm, peltier

I'm making a fermentation chamber using a Peltier element ([TEC1-12706](http://peltiermodules.com/peltier.datasheet/TEC1-12706.pdf)). As recommended by the data-sheet (\$V_{max} = 14.4 V, I_{max} = 6.4 A\$), I'm using a 12V/3A 4 kHz PWM power supply.

I want to smooth/filter PWM output (e.g., RC circuit) so as to increase the lifetime of the Peltier element. The problem is that I also need to reverse the current direction (for fast heating & fast cooling).

How can this be done?

Comment: Check out H-bridge.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use an LR, with RC you'll have quite some losses. Have a look at all those class D amplifier output stages, you should have no trouble with reversing as far as the filtering goes. Of course you'll need an H-bridge to reverse your peltier. You might want to look at some of the popular motor drivers.

Comment: PWM + LC = buck converter.

Comment: Your statement is necessary but not sufficient.